# Is it possible to do complex row by row operation efficiently by Spark like ETL tools?

Tags: pyspark, etl, data-warehouse, informatica

Let us consider the following scenario

```
 We have table A,B,C,D
 Select each row from Table A using complex SQL 
   Loop
     Based on condition 1 
          Insert in Table B 
          Update Table D 
          Delete from table C
      Based on condition 2 
          Insert, Update in Table B 
          Delete from Table D 
          Update table C
.
.
  Based on condition N similar actions .
   Manipulate some Global variables , Local variables  and based on that do additional processes.
 End Loop .
```

ETL tools ,Oracle Pipelined parallel we can do it  efficiently as well as moderately easy.
Is the above   possible in Spark ?

too complex inefficient sequential op.

Comment: Many Thanks @koushik Roy . . Appreciate. Thanks .

Comment: sorry, i dint answer but you can do anything using a programming language like spark. And based on your requirement SPARK is suitable than informatica or any ETL tools. I would use pyspark or something that has more power.

Comment: Thanked You for formatting . Spark does not have read write global variable concept ng . 2nd row by row loop processing is very inefficient in spark. it defeats it's lazy execution model as well as it becomes sequential. Feel this kind of scenarios we still need ETL tools. Just wanted to confirm from experts.

Comment: Additionally We can not use DML inside UDF. One can suggest using streaming with micro batch but feel that will be a hack i.e. still a sequential processing  as well as it does not address the issue of Global read write variable . Hope stackoverflow community will understand just trying to clear my understanding or any misconception of mine in this thread.